# What exactly is the argument in requestAnimationFrame callback?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

Just run this:

```js
function requestAndDraw() {
  requestAnimationFrame((t) => {
    console.log(`T: ${t} P.now:${performance.now()}`);
  });
}

intId = setInterval(requestAndDraw, 20);
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(intId), 1000);
```

It prints something like this:

```
T: 1164.656 P.now:1176.300000000083
```

I wonder what is the reason for 12ms difference?
It took some time to execute some other callbacks registered with `requestAnimationFrame`? It's just some overhead related with interpreting js? or what? 12ms isn't somthing i'd throw away in this context.

Comment: It's logging exactly the same values for me (I just edited your question with a running demo, click "run code snippet"). Also, the question in your question's title and the question in your question's body don't match, you're asking two different questions here. The answer for the title may be this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp

Comment: In what browser is this occurring? I don't get the same behavior, only ~1ms difference in Chrome v66

Comment: As for my browser - Chrome v66/Ubuntu 18.04. So this is kinda odd. As for the question - I'll be less general in question title next time. And I was unaware of the "Run code snippet" feature - thank you for editing. Also... When I run this snippet i get the same 1ms difference, yet when I copy-paste it to DevTools console, i get those 12ms - seems like a reason for another question) Not sure how to call it though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument is a [DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp), just like what [Performance.now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) is supposed to return, even if it isn't the one returned by this method.

---

So first let explain the difference in precision you are seeing: Recently a major security issue has been discovered in the majority of CPUs, known under the names of [Meltdown and Spectre](https://meltdownattack.com/).
These attacks can be perpetrated from a web browser, but requires the *DOMHighResTimeStamp* returned by *Performance.now*. A quick-fix / "mitigation", Firefox found, was to lower the resolution of this *DOMHighResTimeStamp*. [*(see more).*](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2018-01/)

Since *requestAnimationFrame* callbacks are scheduled to fire the next frame (i.e ~16ms after previous call) the DOMHighResTimeStamp passed from this method doesn't require this *mitigation*, hence you still have the full precision in **this** *DOMHighResTimeStamp*.

---

Now to answer the title's question, the DOMHighResTimeStamp passed in `requestAnimationFrame`'s callbacks should represent the calling time of the stack of all the callbacks for this frame.
Indeed, *requestAnimationFrame*  only store the callback parameter in a stack, and all the callbacks in this stack are then called when the frame occurs (just before the next *painting* operation).
This means that all the callbacks for the same frame will share the same exact *DOMHighResTimeStamp*, without any regard to how long the previous callback took.

However it should be noted that both in Chrome and in Firefox, the timestamp is actually set when the browser receives the monitor's V-Sync signal, not when they call the callbacks. <sub>This explains some rare case where you can have negative results while measuring the time between rAF() using `performance.now()` and the timestamp passed in the callback.</sub>

```js
function long(time){
  var now = performance.now();
  console.log('long');
  console.log({
    'rAF time': time,
    'Performance time': now,
    'diff': (now - time) + 'ms'
  });
  console.log('________________________');
  // wait 50ms
  while(performance.now() - time < 50) {
  }
}
function short(time) {
  var now = performance.now();
  console.log('short');
  console.log({
    'rAF time': time,
    'Performance time': now,
    'diff': (now - time) + 'ms'
  });
}
// our two functions will be stacked together to fire in the same frame
requestAnimationFrame(long);
requestAnimationFrame(short);
```